# Rails rendering content_for not working for partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, render, partials

I am using a Rails 2.3.8 application. I have a layout file that contains
`<%= yield :head %>`

I called the following code in different parts of my application:
`<% content_for :head do %>`
`<meta name="keywords" content="" />`
`<% end %>`

I tried to add that code in a view file `home` it worked. I called it from patial `_abc` that is called from `home` it also worked as expected by adding the `meta` code in the `head` part. But when I added the code inside partial `_def` that is called from `_abc` which is called from `home` the `meta` tag did not show up!!!

I didnt usderstand what is going on... and how can bypass this problem

UPDATE: The case that did not work was:

home.html.erb:
`<%= render :partial=>"_abc"%>`

_abc.html.erb:
`<%= render :partial=>"_def"%>`

_def.html.erb:
`<% content_for :head do %>`
`<meta name="keywords" content="" />`
`<% end %>`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this mean you have content_for :head *twice* (ie once in _abc and also in _def) both vying for position? IF so - not surprising it'll only pick one or get confused. Otherwise - can you clarify? thanks

Comment: Maybe you can post the relevant content of each file to help us understand what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Taryn No I only placed that code in one place at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I got here with a similar issue.  Figured I'd post my issue/solution in case someone else lands here.

Which file is <%= yield :head %> in?  I had this issue and it turned out my yield was in the "/layouts/application.html.erb" file...  But the view being called was using a different layout file i.e. "/layouts/listings.html.erb".  once I moved the yield into the correct file, everything worked fine, and I had pretty much the same setup you described.